# Iterating over groups into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
                 A   B
    0   2002-01-16   0
    1   2002-01-16   4
    2   2002-01-16  -2
    3   2002-01-16  11
    4   2002-01-16  12
    5   2002-01-17   0
    6   2002-01-17 -18
    7   2002-01-17  16
    8   2002-01-18   0
    9   2002-01-18  -1
    10  2002-01-18   4

results = {}
grouped = df.groupby("A")

for name, group in grouped:
    if (df["B"] >= 10).any():
        results[name] = df.loc[df["B"] >= 10].head(1)
        print(results[name])
    elif (df["B"] <= -10).any():
        results[name] = df.loc[df["B"] <= -10].head(1)
        print(results[name])
    else:
        results[name] = df.loc[df["B"] > -10, :].tail(1)
        print(results[name])
```

Output:

```
            A   B
3  2002-01-16  11
            A   B
3  2002-01-16  11
            A   B
3  2002-01-16  11
```

I want to iterate and get **one result per each *A group***, with the next conditions:

- If any *B column* value is >= 10 or <= -10, add just the first to "results" and skip to the next group to continue iterating.
- If there is not any *B column* value >= 10 or <= -10, add the last value to "results" and skip to the next group to continue iterating.

The desired output would be:

```
            A   B
3  2002-01-16  11
            A   B
6  2002-01-17 -18
            A   B
10 2002-01-18   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains two errors that prevent the correct output. The first, and most obvoius, is that you are not using your `group` in the `for` loop. Instead you operate on the full `df` frame. That is why you get the same result for every entry.

When that is fixed, you will get *almost* the expected result. Not exactly, though, due to your second mistake. According to your description, you want to equate `>= 10` and `<= -10`. Your code, however, executes first the greater than check and if that one is successful, it will generate your output. Thus, the result for group `2002-01-17` will be 16, rather than -18.

The fix for the second problem is to ensure that you test for both the conditions in the same `if`clause, generally using an `or`. However, in your current situation, it is possible to collapse these two tests to one, using absolute values (the `abs()` operator). This is somewhat of a special case (albeit pretty common), though. It is good to understand both this and the more general way, using `or`.

This will reduce the number of cases to two, removing the `elif` line. In addition, it is possible to do some minor modifications to increase readablity. That taken together will leave you with someting similar to:

```
results = {}
grouped = df.groupby("A")

for name, group in grouped:
    if (abs(group["B"]) >= 10).any():
        results[name] = group[abs(group["B"]) >= 10].head(1)
    else:
        results[name] = group.tail(1)
    print(results[name])
```

which generates the wanted output:

```
           A   B
3 2002-01-16  11
           A   B
6 2002-01-17 -18
            A  B
10 2002-01-18  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, following your approach:

```
# we'll use this function to get output
def get_values(df):

    # check the condition
    if any(df.loc[(df["B"] >= 10) |(df["B"] <= -10),'B'].values > 0):
        # spit correct value
        val = df.loc[(df["B"] >= 10) |(df["B"] <= -10),'B'].head(1)
    else:
        val = df['B'].tail(1)  
    return val

df.groupby('A').apply(get_values)

A             
2002-01-16  3     11
2002-01-17  6    -18
2002-01-18  10     4
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use loop, try this:

```
df["C"] = df["B"].apply(lambda x: abs(x)>=10)
df.groupby("A", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[x["C"]].head(1) if not x[x["C"]].empty else x.tail(1))[["A", "B"]]
```

result

```
Out[315]:
            A           B
    0   3   2002-01-16  11
    1   6   2002-01-17  -18
    2   10  2002-01-18  4
```